# Распознать RTP EVENT

Tags: c++, rtp

Требуется распознавать `RTP event` приходящие с IP-телефона.
Выловив эти пакеты с `WireSharkом` выяснил следующее:

1. Первые `12` символов - заголовок `RTP` (можно откинуть, предполагая, что
   он верный).
2. Затем идет символ, отвечающий за тип нажатой кнопки.
3. После `2.` идет символ отвечающий за начало события(`4a`) или за конец (`ca`).
4. Следом идут `2` символа отвечающих длительности события.

Список символов отвечающих кнопкам:

- Кнопка:`0` - `00`
- Кнопка:`1` - `01`
- Кнопка:`2` - `02`
- Кнопка:`3` - `03`
- Кнопка:`4` - `04`
- Кнопка:`5` - `05`
- Кнопка:`6` - `06`
- Кнопка:`7` - `07`
- Кнопка:`8` - `08`
- Кнопка:`9` - `09`
- Кнопка:`*` - `0a`
- Кнопка:`#` - `0b`

Предположим, что сообщение пришло в переменную `uint8_t* data`, затем я копирую интересующую меня часть (`13` и `14` символ) в другую переменную:

```
uint8_t a[2];
memcpy(a, data + 12, 2);
```

Теперь вопрос: Как распознавать нажатия кнопок и как в `C++` задать значения кнопок (в виде байтов) из списка выше и как их сравнивать с `a`.?

Comment: Я правильно вас понимаю, что, например, кнопка 8 - это символы "08", т.е. байты 0x30 0x38?

Comment: Посмотрите обновленный ответ - теперь это оно? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ `@Harry` не совсем корректен.
Сейчас объясню почему это так и как будет правильно (дошли руки до реализации).

*Небольшая справка: при нажатии на кнопку приходит не один пакет `RTP EVENT`, а несколько(количество зависит от модели телефона), которые улавливаются `WireSharkом`: часть - `begin_event`, часть - `end_event`.

При нажатии кнопки приходят пакеты следующей структуры: `RTP + RTP EVENT`*

**RTP:** 
 
Заголовок `RTP` сообщения состоит из `12` байт. В данном случае нас интересует второй из них, т.е. `8-15` биты заголовка.

- `8ой` бит: используется на уровне приложения и определяется профилем. Если это поле установлено, то данные пакета имеют какое-то особое значение для приложения. (© Википедия :) )
- `9-15` биты: указывают формат полезной нагрузки и определяет её интерпретацию приложением.(© Википедия тоже :) )

*Что это значит в рамках этого вопроса:*
 Как я выяснил из кучи трейсов, `8ой` бит - маркер начала какой-то секции трансляции, т.е. маркер переключения на другой тип вещания. А вот биты `9-15` указывают какой тип вещания сейчас последует. Например: трансляция данных с кодеком `PT=ITU-T G.711 PCMA` имеет значение `0001000`, а вот `DTMF` имеет значение `1100101`.
Значит, чтобы уловить, что пришел не просто `RTP` пакет, а `RTP EVENT` пакет и причем отделить первый пакет от других приходящих при нажатии этой кнопки, надо чтобы второй байт равнялся `11100101`.

**RTP EVENT:** *(не буду подробно описывать, напишу только то, что имеет значение)*
`RTP EVENT`(`RFC2833`) состоит из `4х` байт. Интересует нас в общем только первый байт, в котором и передается значение кнопки. Сейчас будет список кнопок и значение данного поля для них:

- Кнопка 0: `00000000` - `(int)0`
- Кнопка 1: `00000001` - `(int)1`
- .................................
- Кнопка 9: `00000009` - `(int)9`
- Кнопка *: `00001010` - `(int)10`
- Кнопка #: `00001011` - `(int)11`
- Остальные не проверял (есть телефоны с большим набором кнопок, но их не было у меня)

В дополнение, можно рассмотреть `9ый` бит `RTP EVENT`: Если он равен нулю, то это `begin`, если он равен `1`, то - `end`. Но отлавливать пакеты по `begin` и `end` - не удобно: надо помнить какой пакет пришел до этого, сравнивать их и т.д. Проще замерять по маркеру в заголовке `RTP`.

**Теперь немного о реализации:** 
Поскольку интересующая нас информация идет в байтах по `8` бит, то, на мой взгляд, для хранения информации удобнее использовать тип `uint8_t`.

Теперь копируем интересующие нас байты из сообщения в переменные (или массив\ `vector` и т.д.) с типом `uint8_t` (если интересующий бит хранится в другом байте, то копируем байт полностью для уменьшения геморроя и кода, если кто захочет разбирать `begin`\ `end` `DTMF` ).

Чтобы определить, что пришел `RTP EVENT` (первый) сравниваем второй байт сообщения с `(uint8_t)229`. Если верно, то пришел `RTP EVENT` в первый раз для нажатия этой кнопки, значит, можно узнать что за кнопка: `uint8_t ch13=` тринадцатый байт переводим в число: `(int)ch13`. А далее по списку выше узнаем какая кнопка нажата.

Остальные пакеты, не удовлетворяющие первому условию можно пропускать - они либо не несут смысловой нагрузки `DTMF`, либо мы и так знаем эту кнопку.

**Готово.** :)

Несколько скринов для упрощения восприятия. На них синим выделено сообщение и информация сообщения. В этой, выделенной синим области и надо отсчитывать байты.

Нажатие кнопки * : первый пакет из этой серии.
[image: Нажатие кнопки *]

Кнопка *: тоже begin_event, но не первый.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Обычный RTP пакет:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно вас понимаю, и два байта, которые вы засовываете в массив - это байт `0x30` (символ `'0'`) и второй символ - то, поскольку первый символ всегда ноль, не проще ли использовать как `unsigned char` только второй байт?

Ну, а сравнивать - как обычное число. `==`, `!=`, `switch`...

Если очень хочется - переносите не в `uint8_t`, а в `uint16_t` и опять же используйте как целочисленное значение. Хотите - создайте даже перечисление.

Или вы не это имели в виду? тогда уточните ваш вопрос.

**Update** По скриншотам у вас просто число `uint16_t` в *little-endian*, соответствующее номеру кнопки - копируйте в него, и получите номер кнопки (кнопка `*` имеет значение 10, `#` - значение 11).

Что-то типа

```
uint16_t button;
button = *(uint16_t*)(data+12);

cout << "Нажата кнопка ";
switch(button)
{
    case 10: cout << "*"; break;
    case 11: cout << "#"; break;
    default: cout << button;
}
cout << endl;
```

Comment: неужели так просто?)
Но мне еще надо узнавать начало это или конец (`4a` или `ca`), их как?

Comment: Я таких на скриншоте не вижу - там идет `45 ba` - но принцип тот же: выбираете тип по размеру, выполняете присваивание, работаете. Можно даже через ссылку работать с данными прямо в пакете.

Comment: м... я не тот скриншот второй вставил. Там на первом скриншоте синим выделено значение кнопки. А после него идет как раз `4a` - начало; `ca` было бы, если бы я выбрал правильный скриншот) Ладно, думаю, что подберу значение для них